# the same dataset api attribute is occasionally retrieved undefined

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

I have a table of users where each has an edit button with some data attributes most of the time I get a correct value when I click the edit button, but it still frequently returns `undefined`.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success editUser" data-username="{{$user->username}}"></a>



<script>
$(document).on('click', '.editUser', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var username = event.target.dataset.username;
      console.log(username);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Sometimes you get `undefined` for the same button on multiple click ? Or for some buttons, you always get `undefined` ?

Comment: It's the first case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one , I hope to help you.

```
<a href="#"  class="btn btn-success editUser" data-username="ssss">sss</a>
    <a href="#"  class="btn btn-success editUser" data-username="nnn">nnnn</a>
    <a href="#"  class="btn btn-success editUser" data-username="xxxx">xxxxx</a>

    <script>
    $(document).on('click', '.editUser', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var username = $(this).attr('data-username');

          console.log(username);
     });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="get_value()" href="#" class="btn btn-success editUser" data-username="{{$user->username}}">click</a>


<script>

function get_value(){
        var username = event.target.dataset.username;
        console.log(username);
}
</script>
```

Comment: didn't change anything. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes it’s not. The same issue